# Optimizing for deviation from target in Pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I am using `pulp` in an attempt to minimize the deviation from a target. In the MRE below, assume that items 1-50 have features A, B, C, D. The optimizer should apportion a "budget" equal to 100%, while attempting to get the average value of feature "A" equal to `tgt_a`. It would be fairly easy to just tell `pulp` to force `a` to be equal to the target, but in real life, it may not be possible to get exactly to the target. In addition, I ultimately want to have the system balance all the various features using a sum of squared deviation method, which makes it even less likely that a perfect solution even exists.

The code below runs fine, but simply minimizes the difference between the actual "A" feature value and the target. I need to square the difference in order to make it useful. However if you add a `**2` to the appropriate line of code, you get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'LpAffineExpression' and 'int'

What I'm looking for is a way to square `a_dev` and then set the solver to optimize the variables to minimize that squared difference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp

def contrib(p, col):
    c = df.loc[p, col]
    return c

df_data = {'A':np.random.randint(20, 50, 50),
            'B':np.random.randint(0, 50, 50),
            'C':np.random.randint(20, 50, 50),
            'D':np.random.randint(20, 100, 50)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
picks = df.index

#Set up variable
pct = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Pct', (p for p in picks), 0, 0.05)

#Create problem
ideal = pulp.LpProblem('Sq_dev', pulp.LpMinimize)

tgt_a = 35

a = [pct[p] * contrib(p, 'A') for p in picks]
a_tgt = [pct[p] * tgt_a for p in picks]
a_dev = (pulp.lpSum(a) - pulp.lpSum(a_tgt))
#I need a_dev to be squared in order to be useful!
ideal += a_dev

ideal += pulp.lpSum([pct[p] for p in picks]) == 1
ideal.solve()

for p in picks:
    if pct[p].value() > 0:
        print(p, pct[p].value())
```

Comment: What about `a_dev * a_dev`?

Comment: >TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied

Comment: That doesn't work; same basic reason.

Comment: So if you want to minimise deviation then minimising the absolute value of the deviation is not difficult - see for example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671123/4988601. Squared difference is not linear so you'll either need to use a different package or come up with a linear approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just what the error message tells you: `pulp` does not define these operations on affine expressions.  This is somewhat like multiplying polynomials, or functions: *you* have to define the operation and write the implementation.

Very simply, you have to look up the basic definition of an affine function, research the operations that *are* supported, and write a function to perform the desired operation given those building blocks.